# Can I have both columns and supercolumns in a single column family?

Tags: cassandra

As in the title, I would like to have both columns and supercolumns in a single column family in Cassandra. Is it possible? I found that Thrift retrieves objects of ColumnOrSuperColumn what may suggest that this is possible.

Comment: Due to a lack of answers, I had to do some investigation by myself. Thrift API has cfType field in ColumnFamily class. This field can take only "standard" or "super". So there is a strict separation between column families and super column families. Thus, the answer to my question seems to be "no".

Answer (score 4):

No. SuperColumns are present to support denormalization-into-a-row (see http://www.datastax.com/docs/0.8/data_model/supercolumns), not arbitrarily nested data.